# ASP.NET MVC ActionLink outside area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

A simple task in MVC, sometimes becomes a hard challenge.

Well,i have an Area called Admin. I've a page named "Forbidden" inside the Shared's directory in this area.

The goal is simple: I need to create an Html.ActionLink that generates a link to return to Home page which is **OUTSIDE** the Admin area.

So i try,`<%= Html.ActionLink("Back","Index",new {controller="Home"})%>`,and its generate :

```
http://localhost/Admin/Home/Index
```

Its wrong!I want:

```
http://localhost/Home/Index
```

How can i create a link from an area to the default controllers structure?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this :

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) %>
```

When using Areas, you should always specify the area your are calling in your ActionLinks by adding a route value as above, If the link is outside the area (as in your case), just use an empty parameter for the area.

---

There's a nice extension that i find essential in any ASP.NET MVC project (**T4MVC**). It makes your ActionLinks look much cleaner and it protects them against errors.

So the above code will look something like this :

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Back", MVC.Home.Index()) %>
```

and when using an area :

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Some Link", MVC.Admin.SomeController.SomeAction()) %>
```

It's a part of the **MvcContrib** project on codeplex [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC)

You should consider using it.

Comment: I tried to get tricky and add this to my AreaRegistration default route, but that didn't work. The manual direct to area = "" works in a regular action link. Thanks.

Comment: And for Form this is how you would do it. `Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", new {area = ""}, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))`