# Area name remains after calling another controller from main project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when I call a different controller from an area, it does not remove the area name from the url.

ex -

http://localhost:1395/Syndicate/Home

here "syndicate" is my area. when I call another action from main project (outside the area) through `<a href="/Login/Logout">` it still remains "syndicate" in the url.

ex -

http://localhost:1395/Syndicate/Login/Logout

how can I avoid this problem ?

I tried `@Html.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "Login", new { area = "" }, null)` this but didn't work

Comment: What you do seems right, both in my experience and also according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3756992/1220550 The answer also gives guidance about using T4MVC which will help avoid this kind of problems and which I can certainly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Logout() {
            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Logout", "Login", new { area = string.Empty },null)';
        }
```

just call this javascript function from anchor onclick,